# Browser extension that searches for a list of search terms in the text and source, in the background

Tags: web-browser, text-search, research

I am looking for some search terms (single words, parts of words, and phrases). I look through webpages, and would currently need to search both the presented page and the source (to see if the search terms pop up in, e.g., the naming of images), repeatedly, for all the terms.

The tool i am looking for has an editable list of search terms, that it looks for (in the background) in the text and source of any opened webpage, showing the results in some way (i.e. with color coded lines in the scrollbar (like some IDEs), find-counts behind the list items, whatever.

Plugin/extension for Chrome or Firefox would be ideal, but if there is another way to have this, i would be content.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Funnily enough, it is unclear to *me*, what you (@Community) are asking. I noted type of software (browser extension), specific MO, even parts of the GUI - what would you like to know more about?

Comment: If you know how to use R, I would webscrape the pages (with the `rvest`-package), transform the scraped HTML codes into a character string and identify your search terms there. But I don't know how well-versed you are with R or similar programming languages (like Python).